# Remove css class containing a particular string

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to select and remove class from an element based on string?

E.g

How to remove `class="s2"` from element `<p class="s2 s4 s5"></p>`

I'm looking for way to select class based on number - e.g **'s' can be string on any signs.**
Please note that the order can be different.

Any suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: Any class containing number 2.

Comment: So you want to remove classes `class2` `s2` `another-class2` and the like? Do you want to remove all of them, or just one at a time?

Comment: i think regx will be the better option for you.

Comment: Yes, anythink with '2'. There will be one class with this number(selector) which will be have to be removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
//Get an array of css classes
var aryClasses = $('p').attr('class').split(' ');

//Loop over array and check if 2 exists anywhere in the class name
for(var i = 0; i < aryClasses.length; i++)
{
    //Check if 2 exists in the class name
    if(aryClasses[i].indexOf('2') != -1)
    {
        //2 Exists, remove the class
        $('.s2').removeClass(aryClasses[i]);
    }
}
```

Here's [a working JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CdPSX/3/)

**EDIT**

As someone pointed out in the comments, the above code will only remove the CSS classes from the first `p` tag (as per your example). The code below will remove all CSS classes ending in two from all `p` elements.

```
$('p').each(function() {
    var aryClasses = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');

    for (var i = 0; i < aryClasses.length; i++) {
        if (aryClasses[i].indexOf('2') != -1) {
            $(this).removeClass(aryClasses[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I may have not make my self clear enough, I'm looking for way to select base on number '2'.

Comment: Remove the class which contains number 2 in its name. E.g Name2, select2, wrapper2, wrapper_2 etc..

Comment: Can you please make some comments in the code to exaplain to me how exacly does it work. Thanks

Comment: That'll only remove them from the first p element

Comment: @Eric, additional sample posted that will remove from all `p` elements.

Comment: @Pete, based on the comments you've left on other answers, it appears that you want to remove the class if '2' existing anywhere in the class name. My code has been updated.

Answer (score 8):

What you're looking for is [.removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass):

```
$('p.s4.s5').removeClass('s2');
```

#### EDIT:

```
$('p').removeClass(function(i, class) {
    var classes = class.split(' ');  //get an array of all the classes
    var remove = [];                 //classes to remove

    $.each(classes, function() {
        if(this.match(/2$/))   //if the class name ends in 2
            remove.push(this); //add it to the list of classes to remove
    });

    return remove.join(' ');
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/dWrfr/)

Comment: Sorry, I may have not make my self clear enough, I'm looking for way to select base on number '2'.

Comment: The only issue with it is you are looking for last character.

Comment: @Pete: I thought that was what you were after.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a function to [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and have it return the classes to remove.

To do that, you can use [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) and [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to build a new string consisting only of the class names that contain your number:

```
var yourNumber = 2;
$("p").removeClass(function(index, classes) {
    return $.map(classes.split(" "), function(value) {
        return (value.indexOf(yourNumber.toString()) >= 0 ? value : null);
    }).get().join(" ");
});
```

Comment: Can we also write this in this way: `$("p").removeClass([class*='2']);` ??

Comment: @Pete, no, we can't. I've seen your comment, I'll try to update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Please note I'm looking for way to select the class based on one character - the rest of the class can be anything.

Comment: Since when did returning `null` from `$.map` remove the element? That's awesome!

Comment: @Eric, that's actually documented :) The function can also return an array that will be flattened into the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("p").removeClass('s2');
```

will work for you (in this case)

Comment: Sorry, I may have not make my self clear enough, I'm looking for way to select base on number '2'.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can do this directly.

```
var class_array = $('#your_html').attr('class').split()
```

This will return all classes as an array.

One way would be to then check against all the elements of class_array, then call .removeClass() on 'your html' if a condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this solution?

```
var ClassSelector = '2';

$('p').removeClass('*' + ClassSelector + '*');
```

Answer (score 0):

@Eric, for your removeClass callback function solution. Works great, as long as you don't use "class" as the second parameter, at least in cases when it will be caught as a reserved word. I just replaced with "c," and it worked fine.